# Problem with getting layout to next page?

Tags: c#, .net

I use a _layout cshtml to get all the same start screen. It works on the index page but when i go to the next the css of bootstrap is missing. I added a bootstrap layout but know it doesnt do the layout on the next screen. I could also send you the zip if you want with all the code. The index false exist out only the layout page without any content when you go to an other page you get the text of the layout but not the bootstrap css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Project</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,400italic,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/jcarousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Theme skin -->
        <link href="skins/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png" />
    </environment>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="container ">
                <!-- end toggle link -->
                <div class="row nomargin">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="headnav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Registreer"><i class="icon-user"></i>Registreer</a></li>
                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" data-toggle="modal">Inloggen</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><img src="img/logo_kraan.jpg" alt="" class="logo" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span10">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top ">
                            <div class="navigation">
                                <nav>
                                    <ul class="nav topnav">
                                        <li class="">
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</i></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Statuten">Statuten</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Bestuur">Raad van bestuur</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Seminaries">Seminaries</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ESCL">Over ESCL</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#">Opdrachten <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu bold">
                                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="OverheidsOpdrachten">OverheidsOpdrachten</a></li>
                                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="PrivateOpdrachten">Private Opdrachten</a></li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Forum">forum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end navigation -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
        </header>
    </div>

    <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />

    </div>

    <environment include="Development">

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jcarousel/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
        <script src="js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
        <script src="js/portfolio/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
        <script src="js/portfolio/setting.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/animate.js"></script>

        <!-- Template Custom JavaScript File -->
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
        <div class="widget">
          <h5 class="widgetheading">Browse pages</h5>
          <ul class="link-list">
            <li><a href="#">About our company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet our team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explore our portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Get in touch with us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <div class="widget">
          <h5 class="widgetheading">Important stuff</h5>
          <ul class="link-list">
            <li><a href="#">Press release</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Career center</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flattern forum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
     

      <div class="span4">
        <div class="widget">
          <h5 class="widgetheading">Get in touch with us</h5>
          <address>
            <strong>Flattern studio, Pte Ltd</strong><br>
            Springville center X264, Park Ave S.01<br>
            Semarang 16425 Indonesia
          </address>
          <p>
            <i class="icon-phone"></i> (123) 456-7890 - (123) 555-7891 <br>
            <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> email@domainname.com
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sub-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="copyright">
            <p>
              <span>&copy;BVBR-ABDC</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <ul class="social-network">
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Facebook"><i class="icon-facebook icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Twitter"><i class="icon-twitter icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Linkedin"><i class="icon-linkedin icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Pinterest"><i class="icon-pinterest icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Google plus"><i class="icon-google-plus icon-square"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Bootstrap template:
https://bootstrapmade.com/flattern-multipurpose-bootstrap-template/

Comment: most likely your reference to the file itself is not relative to the root and/or not relative to the location you're on. Anyway, that being said: please add code/html to actually see what could be a problem

Comment: which page do you want to see

Comment: without seeing your _layout.cshtml and index.cshtml It is impossible to point you to the right direction

Comment: This is not answerable when we cannot see the relevant files.

Comment: this question is like going to a garage and saying "my car sometimes doesn't start" but then not actually showing the mechanic the car. I'm not really sure how you think anyone will be able to magically know your problem without seeing the code that causes it? We're good, but we're not that good :-)

Comment: @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

Comment: ths is the index

Comment: That tiny bit clearly has nothing to do with your CSS though, does it? And surely your page has more than that in it? Also please edit your question to include the code, the comments are not the right place for it. Thanks. It would also help to see the code in the layout file as well.

Comment: @joachimsoetinck What does that single line have to do with anything?  It sets the page title.  Please include the relevant files affecting your problem.  It's your responsibility to provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: I added the code

Comment: So when you load "another" page (is that _any_ other page, or just a specific one?), what happens in your Network tab as it loads? Is there a failure on some of the CSS files? if so, what problem occurs? Do you get a 404 or something? Or does it just never load the CSS? Is this other page definitely set to use the layout file, and not have its own separate layout?

Comment: The text is on the page but nog the CSS

Comment: Yes you already said that in the question. But that wasn't what I asked. Do you understand how to look in your browser's developer tools and watch the network requests? we need to start to debug...i.e. we need to understand what is actually happening to the page, rather than just reporting the symptoms.

Comment: it Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: ok so it means the URL to the file was incorrect. Check the URL it's trying to use to access the CSS. Possibly if your other views are in sub-folders then the URL may no longer be correct relative to the view's URL. Or perhaps these views are not in fact using the same code to load the CSS. We don't have enough information about your application to be sure. Either add more info or try to debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

All the file references you use in this sample are relative to the page path, so the files need to be there. Since ASP.net will start the default "home" page at (for instance) at http://localhost:33333/ the browser will request that url + css/filename.css and this will work for the first page.

Although if you navigate to http://localhost:33333/Home/Index (which is essentially the same page) it won't work anymore, because the browser will request the css at url + /home/index relative path + css/filename.css (resulting in not finding http://localhost:333333/home/css/filename.css )

You can resolve this quite easily by altering your layout.cshtml from this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to this:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--        ^                                                      --->
```

as you can see there is an added slash (/) before the file path. This will instruct the browser to *always* use the root of the url and not a *relative* path to the current location.